# Matching operators

Tags: c#, regex, operator-keyword

I have a text input containing lots of operators, variable and English words. From this input I have to separate all the operators alone.

As of now I'm using regular expression matching, so the number of operators matched depends on the regular expression. problem I get are '= is matched with <=', '& is matched with &&'. I need to match both = and <= separately.

Is there any better way for matching the operators other than regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably is. But as an alternative, you could have your regex as (e.g.):

```
[><=&|]+
```

(Modify to your specifications - not sure if you want addition, subtraction, `++` for incrementing etc too).

The `+` means "one or more" and so the regex matches as many characters as possible, meaning that if `<=` is in the text, it will match `<=` rather than `<` and then `=`.

Then, only once you've extracted all the matches, loop through them all and classify them.

Comment: thanx. how can i miss '+' , it solves most of my problems. now my question looks really dumb.

Comment: now the problem is "c=a+++b" your logic takes +++ as single operator. Need to catch that.

Comment: use alternation, catch the ++ as a discrete token first, and *then use the expression here.

Comment: Woah, didn't know such thing as a +++ existed. In that case I recommend @sweaver2112's answer - use alternation and put the longer operators first, e.g. `(&&|<=|[&<]=)`. Since regex goes left-to-right, the `&&` will be matched first if it possibly can.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: `c=a+++b` is `c = a++ + b` without any layout.

Comment: @Borodin exactly, then this logic will fail need to look for some other way to match it.

Answer (score 2):

as far as regex goes, you could have the pattern match the special (compound) case first, then the catch-all last with simple alternation. In your simple input case:  `/<=|&&|=|&/`.   this isn't necessarily terrible, you can still put whatever your catch-all is after that: `/special1|...specialN|special-chars-catch-all/`

this technique could be useful in some cases where a greedy expression would just get the whole thing, like:  `if($x==-1)`, you would want `==`, not `==-`

Comment: sorry i didn't get you properly. u r saying tht we can use regular expression like "/<=|&&|++|--|&+-<>=/" .

Comment: Well, yes. `|` means "OR". And remember to escape special characters (like +). For example, `/[<>=]=|&&|\+\+|--|[&+<>=-]/` (and division, multiplication, modulus, ||, etc). Longer operators before shorter operators, and escape special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the extended variants in your RE language.

In most RE languages /[<](?![=])/ will match "<" but not "<=" and not "=", for example.  The (?! ... ) means "except when followed by ...". The term for this is **Negative Look-ahead Assertion**.  These are sometimes spelled differently, as they are less standard than most other formations, but they are usually available.  They never consume more characters, but they create slower matches.

The "except when preceded" or **Negative Look-behind Assertion** is sometimes also available, but you may wish to avoid it.  It is seldom clear to a reader and can create slower matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might still be able to get regex to do what you want.

If you want to completely abandon it, please forgive me and ignore my suggestion :)

If you want to use regex to detect *just* = then you could use `[^<>=]=[^<>=]` which means 'match the equals only when it is not preceded or seceded by < > or another =.

You could use `{1}&` with ampersands to detect one (and only one) ampersand.

(NB you might need to escape a couple of those symbols with `\`)

I hope that might help.  Good luck.

K.

Comment: sorry if i'm not clear with the question . i need to match both = and <= separatley. as = is assignment operator and <= is realational. i need to match them and maintain their functionality.

Comment: Sure, in that case you could have a separate regex for each operator to see if it matches. One for =, one for <= etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you do multiple passes, you can also find the compound operators and then replace them with other characters before a pass that finds the simple ones.

This is often a useful approach anyway: to slowly overwrite your interpreted string as it is processed, so that what is left when you are done is just tokens.  RE processors often return index ranges.  So you can easily go back and overwrite that range with something no one else will match later (like a control-character token, a NUL, or a tilde).

An advantage is that you can then have debug code that does a verification pass to check that you have not left anything around uninterpreted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no need to answer twice. Simply edit one of your answers (the little `edit`-link beneath your answer) to extend it. Always try to judge if it really is worth another answer (better to say: a different (!) approach for a solution towards the same question). For me this answer seems more likely to extend your other answer.